# Parsing a json output string

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python, How to convert this to a json string? I like to get the first line of the commitMessage in below output(op) ? thanks in advance

```
>>> op = subprocess.Popen('ssh -p 29999 server-name.com gerrit query --commit-message --format=JSON Ib3856dcf0826942787c3d5a076eb6888dae9k2be', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='../').communicate()
>>>
>>> op
('{"project":"mtt/proprietary/fg","branch":"master","id":"Ib3856dcf0826942787c3d5a076eb6888dae9k2be","number":"1857599","subject":"store Gain","owner":{"name":"owner1","email":"one@mail.com","username":"user1"},"url":"https://server-name.com/1857599","commitMessage":"my commit message\\n\\nChange-Id: Ib949999d3f4d94299993d5a076eb681c4aaaa2be\\n","createdOn":1478281199,"lastUpdated":1478732989,"sortKey":"0041150d001ad179","open":false,"status":"MERGED"}\n{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":4}\n', None)
>>> js = json.loads(op)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: `op` is a `tuple`, perhaps you meant `json.loads(op[0])`

Comment: Try this 
`json.loads(json.dumps(op))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes have two standard output streams: stdout and stderr. One for regular output and other for errors. `communicate` returns a tuple with two elements: first is stdout and second is stderr. You need the first:

```
json.loads(op[0])
```

Comment: thanks, I get error `raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 1 (char 597 - 651)` any idea?

Comment: Your json is not valid. Comma is missing before  `{"type":"stats",`

Comment: yes `\n{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":2}\n` is the second item in the gerrit query output, checking how to make gerrit query stop printing that, or can I make python to ignore it?

Comment: `op = op[0].split('\n')[0]` did it, :), dirty ?

Comment: No, not dirty. You need the first line and this code does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `op` variable returned from subprocess is not a string, it is a tuple of 2 elements.
Just do: `js = json.loads(op[0])` instead, to parse the first element, which is the json string you are attempting to parse